# Packages installed in miniconda but not anaconda

Tags: anaconda, conda, xgboost

I did not manage to install xgboost so I install something call miniconda. With the miniconda prompt i can use `pip install xgboost` works.

When I did it again I get the answer:

```
"Requirement already satisfied: xgboost in c:\users\anne-sophie\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost-0.6-py3.6.egg"
```

But when, in my jupyther notbook I do "import xgboost" I get an erreur:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-745aa3a2d734> in <module>()
----> 1 import xgboost as xgb

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xgboost'
```

It seems that everything is installed in `C:\Users\Anne-Sophie\Miniconda3\Lib\site-packages` instead of `C:\Users\Anne-Sophie\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages` and Anaconda must be connected to Anaconda3 and not mini conda3".

Do you have any ideas how I can connect anaconda to miniconda? I managed to make it work by copying lib and library from miniconda to anaconda but I am sure it might exist a way to do it easily.